# Accessing array elements in query postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently building a query to retrieve some data from my db, I need to access the documents stored in an array, this is how the table
`crm_company` looks:

```
+ company_id +         documents_avaiable       + 
-     1      - [71788176,98705180,21468287,...] -   
-     2      - [11218494,12825726,10353038,...] -
```

I have another table for users by document `crm_user` which looks like this:

```
+ user_document +     email     +
-   71788176    - abc@email.com -  
-   98705180    - def@email.com - 
-   11218494    - hef@email.com -
```

What I want as a final result is:

```
+ user_document +     email     + company +
-   71788176    - abc@email.com -    1    -
-   98705180    - def@email.com -    1    -
```

I just have tried somehing like the following:

```
select documents_avaiable[0] from crm_company where crm_company.id = 1
```

But I'm still unable to retrieve the documents from array.

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but more complicated than necessary. it is a really bad idea to store "foreign keys" in an array, and now you know why. Normalize your data model!

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us some data from "another table". Show your desired result from this two tables from the data you presented and will present...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is not that easy for me to modify the models, is an external datasource, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's too late to follow the advice in the comment of Laurenz Albe then do this:

1. Use a query (or create a view) to have the list of company documents normalized

   ```sql
   create view company_documents as
   select t.company_id, l.document_id
   from crm_company t
   cross join lateral
   (
     select unnest(t.documents_avaiable) as document_id
   ) l;
   ```
2. Access documents' details in other tables by `document_id` using `join`

   ```sql
   select cd.document_id user_document, cd.company_id company, d.email
   from company_documents cd join crm_user d 
   on cd.document_id = d.user_document;
   ```

Comment: Note that `cross join lateral (select unnest(...) as document_id) l` can be simplified to `cross join lateral unnest(..) as l(document_id)`